# Pegar dados de um rss

Tags: php

Muito bom dia a todos!. Pessoal eu fiz este script, porém, na nova versão do PHP ele não está funcionando. Vocês sabem como eu posso fazer esse código na nova versão ?

```
<?php
// Mostrar Data na Tela.
$titulo = array();
$data = array();
$link = array();
$quantos = 0;
$exibir = 12;
$limite_title = 100;

foreach(file_get_contents("https://www.clubhost.com.br/cliente/announcementsrss.php")->channel->item as $item)
{
$titulo[] = utf8_decode(substr($item->title, 0, $limite_title)."...");
$link[] = $item->link;
$data[] = utf8_decode($item->pubDate);
$quantos++;
}

for($i = $quantos-($exibir+1); $i < $quantos-1; $i++)
{
if($titulo[$i]!="")
{
echo
'
<li>
<a href="'.$link[$i].'" target="_blank" title="Leia mais clicando aqui!">'.utf8_encode($titulo[$i]).'
</li>
';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Qual o erro que esta dando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não informou qual o erro, só consigo supor pelo código que o problema é na linha:

```
foreach(file_get_contents("https://www.clubhost.com.br/cliente/announcementsrss.php")->channel->item as $item)
```

Troque o "file_get_contents" por "simplexml_load_file", e me surpreendo que isso estivesse funcionando antes pois, da forma que você faz, está tentando tratar uma string como um objeto xml.